# Can i change what's inside the fill tag of an svg element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following LinearGradient inside the defs tag of an SVG:

```html
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="left-to-right">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#000000">
      <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
    </stop>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff">
      <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
    </stop>
  </linearGradient>

  <linearGradient id="right-to-left">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#000000">
      <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
    </stop>
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff">
      <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
    </stop>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

I am using the following inside the svg tag to change the fill of the SVG, and it works properly.

```html
fill="url(#left-to-right)"
```

Though, i want to be able to change the fill from what is in:

```html
<linearGradient id="left-to-right">
```

to:

```html
<linearGradient id="right-to-left">
```

(so, basically change this:

```html
fill="url(#left-to-right)"
```

to this:

```html
fill="url(#right-to-left)"
```

)

Is there a way to do that using Javascript and vice-versa? (going back from "right-to-left" to "left-to-right")

Comment: Try using the [setAttributeNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) method

Comment: setAttribute is simpler as you wouldn't have to pass an initial null argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can get your svg element using `document.getElementById()` and then change its `fill` attribute with [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method.

If you also want to restart the animation every time you change the fill, you could write something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('animate').forEach(element => element.beginElement());
```

`document.querySelectorAll('animate')` will find all the elements with `<animate>` tag (note that there is no dot before `animate`, so it's not a class name). And then for each of them you call `.beginElement()` that restarts the animation. For description take a look at [SVGAnimationElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement)

```js
function change() {
  const rect = document.getElementById('rect');
  const fill = rect.getAttribute('fill');
  rect.setAttribute('fill', fill === 'url(#left-to-right)' ? 'url(#right-to-left)' : 'url(#left-to-right)');
  document.querySelectorAll('animate').forEach(element => element.beginElement());
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" width="40" height="40">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="left-to-right">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#000000">
        <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff">
        <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="right-to-left">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#000000">
        <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff">
        <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect id="rect" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="url(#left-to-right)"></rect>
</svg>
<br>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Sorry ,im a newbie at JS and trying to understand your code =P what does `document.querySelectorAll('animate').forEach(element => element.beginElement());` do? i found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) but you haven't added a `class="animate" `anywhere in your code, does it target the `<animate></animate>` tags instead? and why?

Comment: @xXnikosXx I've added more information to my answer. In short, `querySelectorAll` uses [css selection rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). If you want to query by class name, you write `querySelectorAll('.class-name')` (with dot). If you don't specify the dot, it will query by tag name.

Comment: I notiecd later that you hadn'y added a dot =P The only thing I don't understand is `.forEach(element => element.beginElement());` but I'm reading about it rn. Thanks for all your help!!!